# Login not working in php mysql code

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make the login page but I am not able to login to the form.

Code for form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Mentor Login</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email or Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email or Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="m_pass" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <span class="psw"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></span>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="btn_log" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
Don't have an Account?
<a class="btn btn-link" href="mentor_register.php">Create Account</a>
</div>
</form>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code for the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_log'])){
    $m_pass = $_POST['m_pass'];
    $usname = $_POST['usname'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from mentor_reg where usname='$usname' AND  m_pass='$m_pass'");    
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
  if ($check == 1){

    $_SESSION['login_ment']=$usname;
 echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<script>alert('Error password');</script>"; 
    }
  }
```

The form is submitting perfectly but users are not able to login. we have tried with both the username and password & email and password to check from database and trying to login. Thanks

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Don't use JavaScript or Meta Tags to redirect a web page. Use [`Location: header`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) instead. Check [PHP the Right Way](//phptherightway.com/) for more up-to-date advice.

Comment: If your query failed you wouldn't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Answer (score 0):

First error:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email or Username">
```

Your input name is "email" and you are catching $_POST['usname'];

Answer (score 0):

Your php code  says

```
$usname = $_POST['usname'];
```

but this value is not sent from the from as you've given email in input field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email or Username">
```

Also can you post the errors please?

Comment: I am not getting any error msg. can you please guide me about usname?